# Locking an object in C#?

Tags: c#, locking

I have the following sample code in some (nonexistent) language:

```
class Node {
int val;
Lock lock;
}
```

What would be the equivalent of that `Lock` in C#?

Comment: First you have to tell us what Lock is meant to do in your nonexistent language. (Complete guess: Is it meant to be an object you can use to create a 'one thread at a time' section in some other bit of your code? )

Comment: Not sure how this is going to help you. You don't need any special object for locking a C# instance unless it's a custom biz object that uses some business semantics in its locking logic... In any case, this seems like a grasp at straws. What are you trying to lock? Make the instance read-only? Threading?

Comment: @ian: when an instantiation of the object "locks" it will only allow one thread to change the object.

Comment: You can't do exactly that on the whole object in C#.  You can protect sections of code with a lock .... answers already below.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, *any* object can be used with thread locking.

So your code could look like:

```
class Node {
int val;
Object lockObject = new Object();
}
```

Within your code you lock the object like:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
         // Do sometthing that needs thread protection
    }
}
```

If you need an inter-process locking object, then you can use a semaphore. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).

Comment: You are being a bit harsh.  I provided suggestions to two ways to lock, threads and semaphores. There aren't many other ways to lock in C# are there?

Comment: I don't think I was that harsh.   Once it was clear that OP was indeed talking about threading, and not some other meaning of the word lock - i removed the -1.  He could have been referring to encapsulation, or database row locking or anything.  He'd given you a keyword to a hypothetical language, and you'd assumed it meant the same as the C# one.

Comment: I think this is what I am after. I found more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx

Answer (score 0):

c# has a lock keyword. You can create an object of type object called lobj or something similar and then use

```
object lObj = new object();
lock(lObj){}
```

Comment: Well you won the race to write an answer .... but I'm amazed that you knew what the question was.  We all could probably have written that ..... but is it what the OP was asking?  Time will tell.  -1 until it is clear that this is what OP needs.

Comment: lol, I took a stab that he wanted to lock something?

Comment: ouch since he accepted a similar answer and linked to an answer on the same stuff then I think this is what the OP needs

Comment: well yes, that is clear *now* - but wasn't clear when he asked the question.  I removed the -1 when it became clear that he was indeed talking about threading, and not something else entirely like database row locking.  Besides, he hasn't accepted an answer as of the last time I looked - someone has upvoted another answer.

Comment: He made an incomment accept 'I think this is what I am after. I found more info at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx –' but apparently hasn't found the button.